# tx-news ignores all flexform settings inside gridelement

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-10.x, tx-gridelements

I'm using TYPO3 10.4.9, gridelements 10.0.0, news 8.5.0 and bootstrap_grids.

I nest elements like section > cols > content element.

When I do this with news plugin, the output is always list view and the plugin ignores all other settings like startingpoint or itemsPerPage, you name it.
Gave me a headache yesterday as I couldn't figure it out. But when I moved the Plugin outside the nested grid, the plugin works like a charm. What do I miss here? Anyone else using a similar setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Answer of another user, which was deleted for no reason, makes me think that it's not a problem related to tx_news.
Removing this context I found a solution, just add the following Line to your setup:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.dataProcessing.10.default.options.resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
```

For information about this are discussed here:
https://gitlab.com/coderscare/gridelements/-/issues/122
and here:
https://gitlab.com/coderscare/gridelements/-/issues/115

I hope this helps anyone.